# How to Interface Camera Module Ov7670 with BeagleBone Black?

Tags: arduino, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I need a link to some tutorial or procedure describing the method to interface Ov7670 with BeagleBone Black running Debian. So far I haven't been able to find any. Please help me in this regard or if you know some tutorial please guide me to it. Thank-You!

Comment: Seriously no one knows anything?

Comment: I posted up some information for you. I'm going to keep poking around and see if I can find anything additional on it, but as I'm sure you already realize by now, there is little information on the net about it. If it gives you any particular errors, post it up and maybe we can figure it out together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how helpful any of this will be, as I haven't personally dealt with it, but I poked around to see what I could find for you. Hope it helps buddy. If it does, come and confirm so others in the future can utilize the information. The information seems to be rather scarce on the internet for this.

**Driver needed for it:**
https://gitorious.org/beagleboard-validation/linux/source/1114ff9f28693ec6893a1a0ddc8df5f57ab89916:drivers/media/video/ov7670.c

**Site with info/etc..:**
http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2012/07/hacking-ov7670-camera-module-sccb-cheat.html